# React-Google-Maps Custom ImageMapType WMS: Wrong tile size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, wms

I am currently working on implementing a WMS ImageOverlay on top of the standard Google Map with React.

I first tested the wms with a website called Metaver:

The Link shows the expected outcome of the wms:
https://www.metaver.de/kartendienste;jsessionid=D41017176A24B2FDBF4100A2890D7A02?lang=de&topic=themen&bgLayer=sgx_geodatenzentrum_de_web_light_grau_EU_EPSG_25832_TOPPLUS&E=561779.77&N=5966630.38&zoom=13.303333333333319&layers_visibility=7039853c21e0d4490dd22d268cb541ce&layers=0edf39759fb42bf4204c9a98daa8c469

**They use:**

- EPSG: 25832
- TILE SIZE: size of the map not 256x256

Screenshot of the Link:

[image]

**Link of Metaver tile**

https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREVIEW_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=CP.CadastralParcel&CRS=EPSG%3A25832&STYLES=&WIDTH=1793&HEIGHT=366&BBOX=559871.4663681758%2C5966241.228792394%2C563687.8841354197%2C5967020.263317106

But when I try to implement the WMS into my application some things are not right.
If you take a look at the parcel in the middle the number "37/73" appears multiple time, but it should appear only once.

This is probably because I took 256x256 as my tile size. Now my question is how do I change the tile that it always matches with the map size as it is in the picture of Metaver.
I know how to get the maps width and height, but when I use them everything on the wms get very small (last screenshot). I think this is because of the function "xyzToBounds". This only works with tiles sizes of 256, right?
When I take the maps width and height something seems wrong with the zoom
Help appreciated

Image of my wms with google maps:

- EPSG: 3857
- TILE SIZE: 256x256

[image]

**Link of my tile:**

https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREVIEW_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=CP.CadastralParcel&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&BBOX=1107419.6657956317,7141052.930514306,1108031.1620219164,7141664.426740589

Image of my wms with google maps:

- EPSG: 3857
- TILE SIZE: size of the map

[image]

Link of my tile(size of the map)

https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREVIEW_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=CP.CadastralParcel&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=972&HEIGHT=414&BBOX=1104973.680890508,7141052.930514306,1105585.177116789,7141664.426740589

```
  const EXTENT = [-Math.PI * 6378137, Math.PI * 6378137];

  function xyzToBounds(x:any , y:any, z:any) {
    const tileSize = EXTENT[1] * 2 / Math.pow(2, z);
    const minx = EXTENT[0] + x * tileSize;
    const maxx = EXTENT[0] + (x + 1) * tileSize;
    const miny = EXTENT[1] - (y + 1) * tileSize;
    const maxy = EXTENT[1] - y * tileSize;
    return [minx, miny, maxx, maxy];
  }

  
  var getTileUrlFlurstuecke = function(coordinates: any, zoom: any) {
    return (
      "https://service.gdi-sh.de/SH_INSPIREVIEW_AI_CP_ALKIS?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng" +
      `&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=CP.CadastralParcel&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=${256}&HEIGHT=${256}&` + 
      "BBOX=" +
      xyzToBounds(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, zoom).join(",")
      );
    };
  
  var flurstuecke = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: getTileUrlFlurstuecke,
    name: "Flurstücke",
    alt: "Flurstücke der Grundstücke",
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 5,
    opacity: 1.0,
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
  });
```

And this is a div where it is possible to active/deactive the wms

```
<div className=' bg-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md'>
      Flurstücke
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={(event) => {
        if (event.currentTarget.checked) {

          map?.overlayMapTypes.push(flurstuecke)
        } else {
  
          const overlayMapTypes = map?.overlayMapTypes.getArray()
          const index = overlayMapTypes?.findIndex((e) => e?.name === flurstuecke.name)
          
          if (index != null) {
            map?.overlayMapTypes.removeAt(index)
          } else {
            console.log(index);
          }
        }
        console.log(map?.overlayMapTypes);
      }}/>
    </div>
```